# How do I get to restart my Javascript code

Tags: javascript, reset-button

For my Higher or Lower game i'm trying to make a reset button. But I just can't figure out how. I've tried it with for, while loops etc. I've searched on the internet but I can't find anything. Im just look for a reset button that "restarts" my javascript from the beginning, just like when I refresh. For my assignment I can't use location.reload().

Here's my javascript code:

```
var randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
var randomNum2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
var goodaudio = new Audio('sfx/Correct-answer.mp3');
var badaudio = new Audio('sfx/thatswrong.mp3');
var picArray = ['images/redcross.png', 'images/greencheckmark.png'];
var score = 0;
var i = 10000;


document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = 'Score ' + score;
console.log(randomNum2);
document.getElementById('rannummer').innerHTML = randomNum;


function checkCorrect(buttonNaam) {
    var correct = false; //Maakt een variable aan
    if (buttonNaam == 'hoger' && randomNum > randomNum2) {
        correct = true;
    } else if (buttonNaam == 'gelijk' && randomNum == randomNum2) {
        correct = true;
        score += 99;
    } else if (buttonNaam == 'lager' && randomNum < randomNum2) {
        correct = true;
    }

    playSound(correct); //Roept functie playSound aan en geeft variabele "correct" mee

}

function playSound(correct) { //Maakt een parameter en ontvangt de variable uit de andere functie
    if (correct === true) {
        goodaudio.play();
        score++;
        document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = 'Score ' + score;
        document.querySelector("img").src = picArray[1];
        document.getElementById('goedzo').innerHTML = "Goed zo! Het nummer was: " + randomNum2;
        document.body.style.color = "lightgreen";
        randomNum2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        document.getElementById('rannummer').innerHTML = randomNum;

    } else {
        badaudio.play();
        document.getElementById('jammer').innerHTML = 'Game over, je score is ' + score;
        score = 0;
        document.getElementById('probeer').innerHTML = 'Probeer opnieuw';
        document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = 'Score ' + score;
        document.querySelector("img").src = picArray[0];
        randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        document.getElementById('rannummer').innerHTML = randomNum;

    }
}

document.getElementById('hoger').addEventListener('click', function () {
    checkCorrect('hoger');
});

document.getElementById('gelijk').addEventListener('click', function () {
    checkCorrect('gelijk');
});

document.getElementById('lager').addEventListener('click', function () {
    checkCorrect('lager');
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just set all your state variables back to their starting values, ie `score=0` etc

Comment: I think that homework questions are discouraged. If you were to ask how it could be done rather than merely for the solution it may be better received